# Replace each unique value in a sorted dataframe column with i

Tags: r

I am new to R, I have this massive data file with a list of user IDs. I want to replace those user IDs with a number i starting from 1 for each id. Is this possible?

Here's what I have:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the examples instead of images as we can't copy it

Comment: My guess is that the final solution will contain something along the lines of `as.numeric(factor(c("jeroen", "akrun", "roman")))`.

Comment: solution by adding in a new column:
 df$identifier <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$id))

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution using a `as.factor` approach:

In `df` you have your input data:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(7001,7001,8001,8002),A=c(1,2,3,4))
df
    ID A
1 7001 1
2 7001 2
3 8001 3
4 8002 4
```

Replace `ID`

```
df$ID<-as.numeric(as.factor(df$ID))
df
  ID A
1  1 1
2  1 2
3  2 3
4  3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` to get the index in the order of occurence of the unique ID's

```
dat$ID <- with(dat, match(ID, unique(ID)))
dat$ID
#[1] 1 1 2 3
```

---

Or use `.GRP` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, ID := .GRP, ID]
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's description,

```
dat$ID <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dat$E) < 0))
```